# Why for-comprehension expands to map+foreach instead of nested foreach?

Tags: scala, foreach, for-comprehension

I suppose that for-comprehension which I see as "for every 'a' create 'x' and then for every 'b' do some stuff with all of vars"

```scala
for {
    a <- Seq(1, 2, 3)
    x = "test" + a
    b <- Seq(4, 5, 6)
} {
    ...
}
```

should be expanded to

```scala
Seq(1, 2, 3).foreach { a =>
    val x = "test" + a
    Seq(4, 5, 6).foreach { b =>
        ...
    }
}
```

but surprisingly check with `-Xprint:parser` shows that it expands to

```scala
Seq(1, 2, 3).map { a =>
    val x = "test" + a
    (a, x)
}.foreach { case (a, x) =>
    Seq(4, 5, 6).foreach { b =>
        ...
    }
}
```

I think it breaks the natural understanding of what's going on in whole for-comprehension, coz now it is firstly define three different 'x' and then executes other stuff. It may be critical if definition of 'x' can produce side-effects so what's the purpose of desugaring to `map`?

Comment: Because that is how [it works](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html). Why does it breaks the natural understanding of what is going on? It should be the same end result. If you have problems with the definition of`x` now you understand why side-effects are bad and why a `foreach` is bad.

Comment: Okay, but what the purpose of expansion using map instead of simple way as I mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is surprising, but it's documented in Scala specification: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops

According to the last rule there:

> A generator  <-  followed by a value definition ′ = ′ is translated to the following generator of pairs of values, where  and ′ are fresh names:
>
> ```
> (, ′) <- for (@ <- ) yield { val ′@′ = ′; (, ′) }
> ```

So when there is a value definition, Scala always inserts a new for-comprehension with a `yield`, which then becomes `map`.

And if you replace the value definition line `x = "test" + a` with a generator `x <- Seq("test" + a)`, the result becomes as expected:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3)
  .foreach(((a) => Seq("test".$plus(a))
    .foreach(((x) => Seq(4, 5, 6)
      .foreach(((b) => ...))))))
```